# Kendo grid number formatting as percentage issue

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, string-formatting, number-formatting

I am displaying numeric value formatted as percentage using the following:

```
columns.push(
            {
                field: key,
                hidden: false,
                format: "{0:p2}"
            });
```

When the field is supposed to display `1.00%` it's displaying `100.00%` like wise any given value `it's adding zeros`, one more value is `65.37%` and output is `6,537.00%`

Any settings that I am missing or anything wrong with the format?
The problem is I am creating grid dynamically and hence I can't show the full grid setup.

In the above you can see I am pushing columns which is an array which will be passed to the function which creates grid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: [
              { id: 1, increase: 1.00 },
              { id: 1, increase: 65.37 }
            ],
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        increase: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
          { field: "id" },
          {
              field: "increase",
              template: '#=kendo.format("{0:p}", increase / 100)#'
          }
        ]
    });

</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 1):

When you format value as percentage there is not build in mechanizm in `kendo` to multiply it. This can only be done by multiplying and dividing the value. [Here some example](http://jsbin.com/fideh/2/edit)

If you want just display value with percent symbol you need to use template:         `template: "<span>#=fieldName# %<\span>"`

Comment: I only display the value in this grid and edit is done in a different grid, how can I make this grid work accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Kendo UI for Angular:
above did not work for me. Kept converting 80% to 800%

This worked:

```
format="#=Percentage# \%"
```

Answer (score 0):

For decimal exactitude:

```
format="##.0000 \%"
```